# Interpretation of loglinear regression

Tags: regression, interpretation, odds, log-linear

Let's assume that gender is the only predictor in binary loglinear regression, in which we are predicting odds of getting paranoid schizophrenia (females are marked as 1 and males as 2). If loglinear coefficient is negative and statistically significant, then we can infer that the odds of getting the disease are bigger for females than for males.
Why is this so?

Comment: Based on "loglinear regression", it seems the log link function was used. Based on "predicting odds" it seems the logit link function was used. So you need to clarify what link function you used.

Comment: I have no idea, I just copied this from a test. Well, it's written, ''not exponentiated loglinear coefficient is negative and statistically significant''

Comment: @a_statistician The log link was used, but by cleverly preparing the data we tricked the model to return coefficients in terms of counts (constant), odds (main effects) and odds ratios (interaction effects). See my answer below.

Comment: How to explain "binary loglinear regression"? It seems your tricky can confuse most of statisticians.

Comment: @a_statistician It is not my trick. It is an absolute classic in statistics. Log-linear models were the dominant method for analysing categorical data befor logit\probit models became dominant. A remainder of that can still seen in the test for independence in a cross-tabulation. There is a likelihood ratio version of that test. The underlying models for that are log linear models. Other then that it is now pretty much a niche method used in demography, parts of sociology, and parts of medical\biological statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology is not consistent across different sub-fields of statistics. In econometrics a loglinear model typically refers to a linear model using a log transformed dependent variable. In other fields (in particular in the biological/medical fields and certain parts of sociology) it refers to a model for patterns in a (possibly high dimensional) cross tabulation. Since you are referring to odds I will assume you are using the term loglinear model in the latter sense.

Lets start with an example. I'll use Stata, but the logic applies to any other Stats program. Say we have the following data:

```
. desc

Contains data from ZA4578_v1-0-0.dta
  obs:             4
 vars:             3
 size:            40
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
husb_career     float   %9.0g      husb_career
                                            * wife should support husband's
                                                career
east            float   %9.0g      east       region of residence
_freq           int     %12.0g                Frequency
                                            * indicated variables have notes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: east  husb_career
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.

. list

     +-------------------------+
     | husb_c~r   east   _freq |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | disagree   west    9297 |
  2. |    agree   west    4403 |
  3. | disagree   east    5639 |
  4. |    agree   east    1770 |
     +-------------------------+
```

Then we can estimate a log-linear model using Poisson regression of the cell frequencies (`_freq`) with the row (`husb_career`) and column (`east`) variable and their interaction.

```
. poisson _freq i.east##i.husb_career, irr nolog                               

Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =          4 
                                                LR chi2(3)        =    5815.16 
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000 
Log likelihood = -20.497687                     Pseudo R2         =     0.9930 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
       _freq |        IRR   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval] 
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------- 
        east |                                                                 
       east  |   .6065397   .0102377   -29.62   0.000     .5868024    .6269409 
             |                                                                 
 husb_career |                                                                 
      agree  |   .4735936    .008664   -40.85   0.000     .4569133    .4908829 
             |                                                                 
        east#|                                                                 
 husb_career |                                                                 
 east#agree  |   .6627738   .0217506   -12.53   0.000     .6214855     .706805 
             |                                                                 
       _cons |       9297   96.42095   881.04   0.000     9109.926    9487.915 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice that I have asked for the exponentiated coefficients (I used the option `irr`).

The constant now shows the expected cell frequency for someone in West-Germany and who disagrees with the statement that women should primarily support their husband's career. Since we estimated a saturated model the expected count corresponds exactly with the observed count.

The main effect of `east` shows that this count changes by a factor 0.61 if you move to east Germany but continue to disagree. This means that we expect for those people who disagree 0.61 East-Germans for every West-German. In general the odds can be described as the expected number of "failures" per "success", so the main effect in a log-linear model is an odds.

Similarly, the main effect for `husb_career` shows that in West-Germany we expect to find 0.47 people who agree with the statement that that wifes should mainly support their husband's career for every person who disagrees with that statement.

The interaction effect shows that this odds of agreeing in East-Germany is 0.66 times the odds of agreeing in West-Germany. So the interaction effect (exponentiated) is the ratio of the odds in the east and the odds in the west. In other words, it is the odds ratio. The logarithm of this coefficient (i.e. before exponentiating) is probably the coefficient you were referring to in your question. Negative number correspond to odds ratios less than 1 and positive numbers correspond to odds ratios more than 1. This is why a negative number means that the odds is smaller in the East than the West.

---

Bonus: In simple tables like this you can get the exact same results with logistic regression:

```
. logit husb_career i.east [fw=_freq], or nolog                                

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =     21,109 
                                                LR chi2(1)        =     161.27 
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000 
Log likelihood = -12675.893                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0063 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 husb_career | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval] 
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------- 
        east |                                                                 
       east  |   .6627738   .0217506   -12.53   0.000     .6214855     .706805 
       _cons |   .4735936    .008664   -40.85   0.000     .4569133    .4908829 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to exponentiate your log odds to frame them in terms of odds ratios. If your response variable corresponds to presence of schizophrenia (1 Yes/0 No), then a lower odds ratio for the non-intercept term implies it that it has significantly lower odds of disease. The converse is also true (as stated in your question) that females have a greater propensity than males.

This is because odds ratios are expressed as just that: ratios. The odds of one event over another. Therefore if the odds for group A is 1.2 and group B is 1.5. The odds ratio is 0.8 for A, such that it's 20% lower.